# ImageJ: Image Stabilizer

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, imagej, image-stabilization

**Problem:** Stabilize a stack of images

**Question:** How could I perform image stabilization without key-point detections? Is there any way to do it?

**I tried this:** http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kangli/code/Image_Stabilizer.html
in ImageJ and it does stabilize. The method used is - Lucas-Kanade. 
I checked many sources and it all needs key-points (like corners, etc) to be defined. [Source: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-25975-3_34]

*Are there any ideas how I could stabilize the stack of frames without key-points?*

Images are microscopic cell images (with cell-division)

Comment: so, why do you not want to use keypoints?

Comment: We see cell movement from frame to frame (but I am interested to keep that movement) and only fix the problem of movement during data acquisition. There are cells (maybe say in frame 10) which could completely be different from the 'reference' frame.

Comment: and your microscope is moving, too?

Comment: yes, unavoidable (as we want to track the cells) :(

Comment: can you post sample images? Or: Is there enough structure in the background to track the background, too? Can you modify for example the background and/or the whole process or are you working with a fixed set of videos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't wan't to use keypoints you need to look at all the pixels in the image and use a measure that can compare the similarity of two images, and try to optimize this similarity.

These measures could be

- Cross Correlation
- Mutual Information

etc.

[ElastiX](http://elastix.isi.uu.nl/) is a tool that supports these two measures and more, and you can allign two images at a time, so you will need to do it sequentially.

However, you will probably get just as good (and faster) results using keypoints.